# React-router : How to trigger $(document).ready()?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my current React + React-router setup my component imports some jQuery things (owl.carousel and magnific popup)

I want to keep the code clean, so the external features are stored in separate file. The code below works only when the page is loaded with direct URL and doesn't work when navigating back and forwards the app. So everything inside `$(document).ready` is triggered only with direct link.

```
import '../jQuery/carousel.js';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    });

    $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
    });
});
```

How do I manage this problem? I tried to use componentWillMount and wrap .ready()  with some custom function, but I can't access `updateJs()` in imported file

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    updateJs();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

No need to use `$(document).ready()` to call jquery function in `react`.

You can make use of `componentDidMount()` just as your `$(document).ready()` to ensure that `DOM` is rendered.

Then access `jQuery` dependent libraries as local variables to apply for `DOM` elemnets. Below example shows some light on this.

```
import $ from 'jquery'; //make sure you have jquery as dependency in package.json

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let owlCarousel = $.fn.owlCarousel; //accessing jquery function
    let magnificPopup = $.fn.magnificPopup; //accessing jquery function
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({ //call directly on mount
    });

    $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and it works of course. But this way code looks hard to read. In actual project it's 100 lines of jquery and 20 lines of jsx which I would like to separate. Do you know any way how I can export function from .js, make an import to component and reference one function like callScripts() or refresh() ?

Comment: One way is to assign your `jQuery` function to `window` object to access in `react` component. And one more thing try to `react` libraries as alternatives to your `jQuery` libraries.