# componentDidMount() issue with starting jquery function - React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router, document-ready

I'm working on ReactJS application. My **$(document).ready(function(){});** stop working after I switch path with React Router Dom. I searched google to find solution for this issue. I find this article:

> [React-router : How to trigger $(document).ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958680/react-router-how-to-trigger-document-ready)

I used code from the answer of this question.
You can see my code here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

import MainRouter from './MainRouter';

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let bootstrapMaterialDesign = $.fn.bootstrapMaterialDesign;
        $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign({});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <MainRouter />
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
};

export default App;
```

This code didn't work. I don't know why.
Here you can see React error:

> TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...)(...).bootstrapMaterialDesign is not a function

Script for raw javascript is: `<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });</script>`
Thank you ☺

Comment: What is the point of using React? When you still need jquery?

Comment: What are you trying to do with jQuery? There are likely ways to accomplish what you need with vanilla Javascript and React.

Comment: In the code you wrote, `let bootstrapMaterialDesign = $.fn.bootstrapMaterialDesign;` doesn't actually do anything. You set that variable to that function, but you don't actually use it anywhere.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I just need to start function of external javascript: bootstrapMaterialDesign. I'm new to React so I don't know how to do this without jQuery. I'll be glad if you tell me :)

Comment: @HarleyLang Can you tell me the right way how to do this?

Comment: @WebCoder yes certainly, I'm happy to help. To clarify, you want to load bootstrap and use its components on your page, is that correct?

Comment: @HarleyLang Yes. When I tried to do it by the code implemented just in index.html it worked but after react router dom action it stopped working. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short walkthrough for how to install and use bootstrap or material-design with React, without needing jQuery.

[Bootstrap is planning to move away from jQuery in version 5](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/08/bootsrap-5-drops-jquery/) so it is important to choose libraries that will not depend on jQuery, unless you are certain that this your want to maintain that leg of your code base (but as other commenters have noted, including jQuery within React is not necessary and in fact, [vanilla Javascript can be just as functional](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)).

---

First, you will need to decide whether you need bootstrap or material design, or both. I will proceed assuming that you just want bootstrap components, in which case all code below applies nicely (for an introduction, [see here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/)). Otherwise, you'll need to follow the material design instructions, [see here](https://material-ui.com/).

Onward with installation:

```
cd path/to/root/react/folder
npm install bootstrap react-bootstrap
```

From that same folder, run `npm start` and let's start editing your files.

---

In your app.js file, change as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Main from './Main.js';

const App () => {

    // Any hooks or other functions needed for rendering router stuff, put it here

    render {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Main.js} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }

};

export default App;
```

Note that this uses functional programming, not classes. So no need for 'didComponentMount'. And I've adjusted your router configurations for a basic, new-to-react setup.

---

Now assuming that your Main.js file has a basic router setup, set it up as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackOverflow!</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Button className="btn btn-primary">Here's a button!</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-simple-bootstrap-example-xydjx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: well the problem is I'm not using official bootstrap but material design bootstrap so I would like to do it by way I did before. However I've seen option of installation npm library on their site too. https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/

Comment: Yes and those depend on jQuery. If you are set on using material design, try installing it with `npm install @material-ui/core` and follow their guide here, it is very simple and requires no jQuery: https://material-ui.com/

Comment: Well, Just say I want to do it via loading `$('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign();` on componentdidmount

Comment: @webcoder sure hit me up on my StackOverflow account, you can DM me on twitter and we can go from there!

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend jquery in react. For any reason if you want to use it. You need to import all these file in your `index.html` place under `public` folder:

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-wXznGJNEXNG1NFsbm0ugrLFMQPWswR3lds2VeinahP8N0zJw9VWSopbjv2x7WCvX"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.6/dist/umd/popper.js"
      integrity="sha384-fA23ZRQ3G/J53mElWqVJEGJzU0sTs+SvzG8fXVWP+kJQ1lwFAOkcUOysnlKJC33U"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js"
      integrity="sha384-CauSuKpEqAFajSpkdjv3z9t8E7RlpJ1UP0lKM/+NdtSarroVKu069AlsRPKkFBz9"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").bootstrapMaterialDesign();
      });
    </script>
```

Here is demo in React: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-frost-6r6vj?file=/public/index.html:571-1620

Comment: As I said. This code works but only when page is just loaded. After React-Router-Dom action $(document).ready will not find new elements again. That's why I'm trying to do this via React

Comment: What do you want to do? Its already triggered jquery. Can you update your code in same sandbox?

Comment: You obviously don't understand that as soon as react-router-dom switch paths. document.ready function will not index new html elements

Comment: I am still not sure. Where you are facing problem. I have updated my sandbox. I can access all ui classes as route changes. Check again here: https://6r6vj.csb.app/users